# page navigation in xamarin.android with back button

Tags: xamarin.android, navigation

how can I navigate to pages with back button in xamarin.android.

I am new to xamarin.andorid.

I had gone through this  [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/page-navigation-in-xamarin-android-app-using-visual-studio-2015/)  but i couldn't find option for back button.and I have another quetion for each page i need to add activity class?

Comment: for the second part of your question research Fragments

Comment: Do you want a slider menu or just back buttons on every page?

Comment: @G.hakim just back button

Comment: Are you working on xamarin.android or xamarin forms ?

Comment: xamarin.android.i ahve mentioned in my post :|

Comment: Because the link that you have shared is Xamarin forms

Comment: @G.hakim oh sorry by mistake i posted wrong link.pls check updated.

Comment: Check my ans out below @NeelamPrajapati

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the AppCompat library in your application:

First, you need to add the toolbar

**toolbar.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"   />
```

Then wherever you need to use it you can use it like this

```
  <include
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

For eg:

**some_page.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFF">
<include
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  layout="@layout/toolbar" />
  .
  .
  .
</LinearLayout>
```

You can use both activities and fragments for your case it's not mandatory that you use activities

If you plan to use Activities for this the way to do it is quite simple :

- Add the Activity to your project.
- Add the toolbar as shown above
- override the OnCreateOptionsMenu and the OnOptionsItemSelected methods in your activity
- For hiding any toolbar menu items you can change in OnCreateOptionsMenu and click events and everything else can be added to OnOptionsItemSelected
- For proper understanding check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/tool-bar/toolbar-compatibility) and you can find an example that answers most of your questions [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar/) and [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/)

Goodluck!

Revert in case of queries

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but there is an override for the back button

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
                base.OnBackPressed(); // will close open activity either closing 
the application or going to your previous activity   
}
```

you can add this to your activity then whenever the back button is pressed do something. base.OnBackPressed(); will run the default back button behaviour and close your current activity. I have often done this to display a confirmation dialogue on leaving a page or to close a fragment on back press

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (_isBlahFragmentOpen)
    {
        ShowActionDialogue("Close blah", "Are you sure you wish to cancel adding blah any changes made will be lost.", CloseDateFragment);
    }

    else
       base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: but there no back button i can see in my next page.then how can  i  override  its event?

Comment: is your app in full screen?

Comment: I think swiping the bottom of the screen upwards by default should display the back buttons for you?  you can force the back button to be visible with the following line `Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility(View.SystemUiFlagVisible);`